# how to get battery level in cordova 2.9 when it need?

Tags: cordova

```
window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);
        function onBatteryStatus(info) {
            // Handle the online event
            console.log("Level: " + info.level + " isPlugged: " + info.isPlugged); 
        }
```

i want get battery level in cordova phone-gap 2.9.they provided this to get battery level and status

but it only fire battery status change but it can't fire when we need it.is there a way to get battery level in cordova?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get battery level when it need.that method fires only when battery status change or battery level change.here i have written a plugin for get battery level any where any time.

create these java files in source folder

create Bat_lev plugin in source folder

```
package org.apache.cordova.example;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;







public class Bat_lev extends CordovaPlugin {


    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("echo")) {
            String message = args.getString(0);
            this.echo(message, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {


    PowerConnectionReceiver p1=new PowerConnectionReceiver();
    Context context=cordova.getActivity();
    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
    p1.onReceive(cordova.getActivity(), batteryStatus);

        callbackContext.success(""+ p1.BAT_LEVEL);
    }




}
```

following java class provide battery level to us

```
package org.apache.cordova.example;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.BatteryManager;

public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static int BAT_LEVEL;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        int currentLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        int level = -1;
        if (currentLevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
        level = (currentLevel * 100) / scale;
        }
        BAT_LEVEL = level;
    }
}
```

write this javascript code to get batterylevel

```
 function bat_level() {
        window.echo = function(str, callback) {
            cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
                callback('Nothing to echo.');
            }, "Bat_lev", "echo", [str]);
        };

        window.echo("echome", function(echoValue) {
            console.log(echoValue);
            localStorage.bat_level=echoValue;//u can use this value anywhere u want
        });

    }
```

and make sure you add this line to config.xml

```
<feature name="Bat_lev" >
        <param
            name="android-package"
            value="org.apache.cordova.example.Bat_lev" />
    </feature>
```

Comment: Hi, is there a possibility to work with Phonegap Build? I have the same problem because I want to get the batterystatus when I need (IOS and Android). Thanks

Comment: couldn't get this to work.. can u share your folder structure and where you have placed these files and their names too?

Comment: hey i did it years ago.now i don't have source codes

Answer (score 2):

You cant work it out in phonegap.However you can write plugins to accomplish it.If you are using android the following code might help , you can tweak it for plugin class.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class BatteryActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    registerReceiver(batteryStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}

private BroadcastReceiver batteryStatusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        Log.d("BatteryActivity", "Battery level: " + level + "%");
    }
};
```

}

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem when trying to access battery level on cordova version 2.3.0. I tried making a plugin but didn't succeed. Then I thought, why not use plain old vanilla js

```
navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {

  var level = battery.level;

   alert(level * 100 + "%");
});

navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {

  var level = battery.level;
  //do what you want with battery level

});
```