# How to get battery level

Tags: java, android, android-intent, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

I am trying to get **Battery Level** of Mobile using ADF. I mean for example if battery charged up to fifty I want to get that value.

How can achieve this?

I don't know exactly can I achieve this by using Android-intent.

If yes, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

here is a code [sample](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721185308/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/getting-battery-information-on-android.html) that explains how to get battery information:

To sum it up, a broadcast receiver for the `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` intent is set up dynamically, because it can not be received through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private TextView batteryTxt;
  private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
      int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
      batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    contentTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryTxt);
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible in ADF mobile also

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
private void getBatteryPercentage() {
  BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             context.unregisterReceiver(this);
             int currentLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
             int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
             int level = -1;
             if (currentLevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                 level = (currentLevel * 100) / scale;
             }
             batteryPercent.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + "%");
         }
     }; 
     IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
     registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
  }

   /* @Override*/
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         batteryPercent = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryLevel);
         getBatteryPercentage();
    }
```

and in `oncreate` add this:

```
batteryPercent = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryLevel);
         getBatteryPercentage();
```

Comment: It showing Type BroadcastReceiver  not found exception in adf mobile

Answer (score 0):

ADF Mobile is an HTML5/Java/Javascript/CSS framework and it depends on Cordova/Phone-gap, so any feature you need try to search on how to do it with Cordova.

If there is a straight way of doing it then you can include a Javascript file to your ADFMobile feature, and you write cordova JS code there, and it could be called on page load or you can call it directly from your javaBean.

Refer to below link to see how to call javascript function from javaBean
http://oracleadfmobile.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/amx-activity-indicator/

But if the feature is not a standard Cordova API, and that's your case (refer to [how to get battery level in cordova 2.9 when it need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478704/how-to-get-battery-level-in-cordova-2-9-when-it-need)), then you will need to check out this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jT4O4Wt9PXw to know how to extend ADF Mobile with Cordova Plugin.